# How to find if two rectangles intersect with the top left and bottom right points?

Tags: java, math

Two rectangles intersect if they are over lapping. Edges and corners count as an intersection. If only given the points for the top left and bottom right of both rectangles. How does one find out if they are intersecting.

Comment: This isn't even a programming question, but rather, a test of whether or not you understand Cartesian coordinates and arithmetic. Get a piece of paper and a pencil. Draw two rectangles. Label the upper left and lower right corners of each with coordinates. Do you notice any relationship between the lower bound of one rectangle vs. the upper bound of the other? Now what about right bound vs the left? What about the inverse relationships? Draw different pairs of rectangles that overlap in various ways and more pairs that don't overlap at all in different ways. Think it over before giving up.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Python solution but it is simple enough.
Let (ax1,ay1), (bx1,by1) and (ax2,ay2),(bx2,by2) be the top left and bottom right points of first and second rectangle respectively. To check whether they intersect or not you can simply compare the x and y coordinates for left-right and top-bottom respectively. For example, if ax1>=bx2 it means the first rectangle is to the left of the second rectangle and so on.

```
def rec_intersect(self, ax1: int, ay1: int, ax2: int, ay2: int, bx1: int, by1: int, bx2: int, by2: int) -> int:
        
        if ax1 >= bx2 or bx1 >= ax2 or ay1 >= by2 or by1 >= ay2:
            return True

        return False
```